# Изменение view.frame.size

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Допустим у меня два `UIViewController`, пусть будет `FirstViewController` и `SecondViewController`. Из `FirstViewController` я модально совершаю показ `SecondViewController`. Из `SecondViewController` у меня `unwind segue` возврат на `FirstViewController`.

Вопрос: будет ли `FirstViewController` изменять ориентацию экрана, то есть менять свой `view.frame.size` при повороте устройства в то время как на экране показан `SecondViewController`. Ведь по сути он остаётся в памяти. Или же это происходит только для `ViewControllers` которые в данный момент на экране.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirstViewController` изменять ориентацию экрана не будет. Изменения будут происходить только для активного контроллера.